# What does iOS storyboard capability attribute under dependencies tag means

Tags: ios, storyboard

In my storyboard I am having following XML attribute

```
<dependencies>
    // More code here
    <capability name="Unknown constraint types" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
</dependencies>
```

1.) What does that capability actually means?

2.) What will affect if I remove that capability?

3.) Is there a documentation/guide that we can learn all the possible attributes and what/when those are using?

Comment: In my case, I manually edited the `.xib` (`xml`) file and somehow it got to a point where 2 incorrect constraints existed: `V` = main view: `V.top = V.top` and `V.leading = V.leading`. Deleting these removed the capability too.